# Converting a symbol to HTML entity code in Android

Tags: android, html, formatting, symbols, spannable

Are there any classes that can take a symbol in a string that is typed in an editText box and replace it with the HTML entity code? Not take the HTML entity code and display the symbol.

For example: if a string is "2∏" is there anything prebuilt that can take it and return "2& #8719;"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using HTML.to (Spanned text).

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is ... the [TextUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html) helper class is included in the Android API

This class has methods for HTML encoding and many other useful functions

```
return TextUtils.htmlEncode("2∏");
```

The documentation for this method is [htmlEncode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#htmlEncode%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Merlin - I thought this would was working fine, but it only seems to encode for the & sign. All other symbols do not get encoded. Any thoughts?